# Fixed volume, maximum area optimization.

Tags: geometry, optimization

**disclaimer:** this question errs a bit on the practical side, I hope it is on topic on this se section.

Today I was cooking a savoury pie. You need to cook some spinach with bacon, then toss everything in eggs, add mozzarella, throw it in the oven and finally profit. The bottleneck of the procedure is waiting for the spinach to cool, because you do not want the egg to cook prematurely.

Say you have a known volume $V$ of a substance that is not solid nor liquid, so you can sort of shape it but not too much. You are constrained in a pan, which we can approximate with a short cylinder of radius $r$ and height $h$. The cylinder volume is approximately twice the substance volume.

Let us also assume that to cool the substance as fast as possible, it is necessary to maximize the ratio $\frac{S}{V}$, where $S$ is the surface of the substance. This is somewhat true, so I'll stick with this assumption.

Question: which is the best arrangement for the substance to cool it as fast as possible? An infinitely thin, infinitely wide plan is not an option, unfortunately. <s>To clarify, any dimension of the final shape must be finite, i.e. given two points $x, y \in S$ it must hold $m < d(x,y) < M$ with $m, M \in R, m>0, M<+\infty$.</s>

As noted in an answer, the condition as it was is not good because it won't allow for a continuous surface to exist. The idea is that every "thickness" must be finite, i.e. given any small enough sphere, it must be tangent to the solution in at most one point, and that the distance between any two points of the solution must be finite.

Pic related:
[image: Yummy!]
(image credits to me)

Comment: Wouldn't you need some sort of lower bound on the diameter of any (sub)shapes you formed? Otherwise I guess you'd end up with some highly discontinuous shape with an infinite number of walls, maybe an infinite amount of rings?

Comment: There is a (badly stated) bound on the min and max dimension in any direction, yes. No infinitely thin and/or tall structures

Comment: The best way to increase the surface area of a substance is to atomize it into a haze of tiny droplets. In principle, there is no optimal solution since you can always make the droplets finer and finer. If you impose a lower bound on the size of the droplets, then that is where the optimum will be.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly what you meant, I will rewrite your "not infinitely thin" condition in the following way:

Every sphere entirely contained in solution volume and with $r < m$ must be tangent to solution surface only in one point, with $m \in R, m>0$.

With you formulation $x,y$ cannot be closer together enough to grant the continuity of $S$ and you will have a cloud of zero dimension dot instead of a surface.

Anyway I think you still need some stronger constraint, the empty spaces between surface point can still be infintely small.

At now, given the fact the solution can be a disjointed set of volumes, i bet on the trivial solution of a set of spheres with radius m, if $V \bmod (\frac{4}{3}  m^3 \pi) \not= 0 $ one sphere will be a capsule.

Comment: You interpreted my bad attempt to constraint it well! Have my +1. I am not sure that the tiny spheres are a valid solution. A tetrahedron seem to have an higher S/V ratio, see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surface-area-to-volume_ratio#Mathematical_examples)

Comment: I mean, possibly tetrahedrons with tiny m-spheres at the vertexes can beat the sphere. Or a cube. Or just anything that is not a sphere, since the sphere is the worst shape in this case

Comment: But I want to maximize the surface. If I wanted to minimize it, the biggest sphere would be the solution.

Comment: Yes the sphere usually minimize $\frac{S}{V}$ instead of maximizing it, but this case is strange. I.e. your tetrahedrons won't satisfy my constraint on thickness, they should became rounded corners tetrahedrons, with a rounding radius equal to m. Given the fact that SA/V is indirectly dependent on chratteristic dimension, you want to choose the smallest m-rounded tetrahedron available, that turns out to be a m-sphere. Everything boils down to the fact that cutting in smaller pieces is always better, but with these rules the smallest pieces are the spheres, so I though abuout spheres.

Comment: I mean, if you start from a m-spere the only way to add some features to the shape while complying the constraint is with a rigid traslation of a copy of the sphere.
But as soon as you start moving you will be wasting your volume money, becouse the surface of a cylinder extruded from a sphere dyameter is always equal to the surface of the sphere slice with the same height, (see [Archimede Hat-Box Theorem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ArchimedesHat-BoxTheorem.html)), but with higher volume cost paid.

Comment: You probably want to have a condition that for every point in the solution volume, there exists a sphere of radius $m$ which contains it and lies entirely inside the volume. Otherwise a cloud of disconnected points vacuously satisfies your condition as well.

Answer (score 1):

As noted in another answer, your condition $m>0$ actually prevents your set $S$ from having any volume at all. You might instead want to say that the set $S$ is a union of balls of radius $m,$ rather than requiring each pair of points to be that far apart, which would imply that the space all around each point is empty.

With that condition, I think your maximum area is achieved by arranging $S$ into separate spheres of radius $m.$ In order to satisfy the maximum diameter condition involving $M,$ you might then need to  place the small spheres in some sort of three-dimensional packing within a larger sphere.

This does not sound like a practical way to cool the ingredients in question, however. Possibly your best static arrangement is to form the spinach in ridges or "fins" of some sort. The arrangement in the picture (concentric circles) is one such kind of arrangement, but parallel lines might be easier to arrange into an efficient shape.